# Pass javascript id value to the input tag id

Tags: javascript, input

I have below javascript code.

```
function setMembers(members){
  var members = members;
  $('.member-search').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
  var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(request.term), "i");
  var recs = $.grep(members, function (obj) { 
    return ((regex.test(obj.first +" "+ obj.last)))
  })
  response($.map(recs, function (item) {
    return {
      label: item.first + " " + item.last,
      value: item.first + " " + item.last,
      id: item.id
    }
  }));
},

response: function (event, ui) {
  $(".members").hide()
  $.map(ui.content, function(obj){
    $("#member-" + obj.id).show();
  })
  if (!ui.content.length) {
    var noResult = { value: "", label: "No results found" };
    ui.content.push(noResult);
  }
}
});
}
```

This is my input tag.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control member-search" placeholder="Choose team member.." id="assigned_to" value="">
```

I want to pass **item.id** value (which is inside the return) to the input value. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign item.id to value, then you need to assign while assigning your response. Please see below the part of code where you need to do it and the complete code as well.

```
response($.map(recs, function(item) {
        return {
          label: item.first + " " + item.last,
          value: item.id, // This is the line you need to change, Here you will assign Id.
          id: item.id
        }
      }));
```

```js
function setMembers(members) {
  var members = members;
  $('.member-search').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(request.term), "i");
      var recs = $.grep(members, function(obj) {
        return ((regex.test(obj.first + " " + obj.last)))
      })
      response($.map(recs, function(item) {
        return {
          label: item.first + " " + item.last,
          value: item.id, //// This is the line you need to change, Here you will assign Id.
          id: item.id
        }
      }));
    },

    response: function(event, ui) {
      $(".members").hide()
      $.map(ui.content, function(obj) {
        $("#member-" + obj.id).show();
      })
      if (!ui.content.length) {
        var noResult = {
          value: "",
          label: "No results found"
        };
        ui.content.push(noResult);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Since I am beginner I can't get where to use this. My js code and Input tags are in two different files.

Comment: you need to use it inside js file. You can write it after the line where you have received the response. Can you create a jsfiddle for your issue, i will add it to desired position if you want.

Comment: Hi Dinu, as per request i have updated the answer. You need to assign it when you get response

Comment: The problem is I can't change that line. Because in my code I want to print first name and last name and same time I want to pass ID to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeid() {
  var e = document.getElementById("assigned_to");
  e.id = "changed_to";
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<span id="assigned_to" onclick="changeid()">
changed value
</span>
```

Note:- First you have to get that element. (You can get that element using id, name, tagName, classname) then you can change that attribute value using particular element.